# Get all user transactions with executeUserSearchRequest

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the Yodlee REST API and am trying to retrieve all user transactions in giving dates.

When calling `executeUserSearchRequest` with the following params, I get only 13 transactions instead of more.

```
transactionSearchRequest.containerType=all
transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit=500
transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit=1
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber=1
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber=500
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientId=1
transactionSearchRequest.searchClients.clientName=DataSearchService
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode=ILS
transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput=true
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType=ALL_TRANSACTION
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate=01-01-2014
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate=04-01-2014
```

Following [this](http://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions) didn't help, since it's not updated.

Update: I've corrected the dates, it was a typo here and didn't appear on the actual request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates sent to Yodlee are ***not*** ISO standard and can be done as
`MM-dd-yyyy`
or
 `MM-dd-yyyyTHH:mm:ss.000Z`.
e.g. :
`"transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate":"03-22-2014T00:00:00.000Z",
"transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate":"06-21-2014T23:59:59.000Z",`

HOWEVER outbound dates ***are*** ISO standard e.g.
`"postDate" : "2014-06-20T00:00:00-0700",`

The REST API needs a lot of work, this is just one of the many issues we have come across. Don't get me started the on the lacking documentation, the incorrect documentation, ignoring HTTP protocols, mixed serialization approaches, java exceptions over the wire...

IMO It is not good enough for a paid for service

:(

Comment: Thanks for that! Regarding the Yodlee REST API, I can't agree more, it's a mess and there is nothing RESTy about it.

Answer (score 0):

transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate=04-01-2014
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate=01-01-2014

Can you try swap those date range values and try? Are you sure these date range has more transactions.

Comment: I still believe that you have problem with your filters. Remove currency, date range filter and find out total number of transactions. It could be possible that there is a I18N conflict of your date range vs what is in Yodlee

Comment: I've removed all filters and it's didn't solve the problem. It was a Yodlee bug, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the fromDate/toDate's value, as it should in chronological order. And the date format is in format as `MM-DD-YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the two date criteria lines and see what you get. If you get>13 txns then try the below:

Assuming you want txns between 01-Jan-2014 to 01-Apr-2014. Do something like this:

transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.fromDate="01-01-2014T00:00:000Z"
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.postDateRange.toDate="04-01-2014T00:00:000Z"

There seems to be a mismatch between your existing txns dates and search criteria you are providing. It could be timezone issue also, so please consider that.

Comment: Note the format that yodlee recieves dates are not the same as what they return!