# Not able to get User Transaction details from Yodlee API

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the http://developer.yodlee.com/TestDrive developer Test API module and using one of the 5 dummy accounts provided by Yodlee, For a particular user I have managed to add a dummy DAG bank account and one real bank account which is visible in [getAllSiteAccounts](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) details Api so its obvious that site have been added.

But while using the [getUserTransactions](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getUserTransactions) API I'm getting error

```
{
"errorOccurred": "true",
"exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.transactionsearch.exceptions.InvalidSearchIdentifierException",
"referenceCode": "_567afa0b-9d5a-4fb4-9db1-afd4f43c39c2",
"message": "Invalid argument value: com.yodlee.core.transactionsearch.TransactionSearchIdentifier@2ad082d0"
 }
```

I also tried using the [executeUserSearchRequest](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) still didn't get any transaction details

```
{
"searchIdentifier": {},
"numberOfHits": 0
}
```

Can you please guide me If I'm using the API's correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use executeUserSearchRequest API to get the transactions. You should check the date range you have provided while searching for transactions and also try to remove itemAccountId.identifier and then search, you should get the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue the only difference though is that I don't have any issues on DAG accounts, but when I used our production account I can't get the user transactions. I was reading this post [Get all user transactions with executeUserSearchRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176579/get-all-user-transactions-with-executeusersearchrequest) and I guess the solution is to make sure that your server/code have the same timezone configuration.